# Is $(X_G, d_G)$ a compact manifold?

Tags: manifolds, topological-groups

Let $G$ a compact topological group act on $(X,d)$ by isometries. We define a relation $\sim$ on $(X, d)$ as follows: for $x,y\in X$:
$$x\sim y \Leftrightarrow x=gy \ \text{ for  some } g\in G.$$
It is clear that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$. Denote
the equivalence class of $\sim$ which contains $x$ by $[x]$ and
denote the set of all equivalence classes of $\sim$ by $X_G$ i.e.
$X_G=\{[x]\mid x\in X \}$ . We define a metric  on $X_G$ as follows:
 $$d_G([x], [y])=\inf _{g, g'\in G}d(gx, g'y).$$
Now I want to know if $(X,d)$ is a compact manifold, is $(X_G, d_G)$ a compact manifold too?

Comment: Fair enough. Take $G = S^1$ acting on $X = S^2$ by rotation around a fixed axis.